# Array Cartesian product in bash

Tags: linux, bash, shell, shell-script

Is there a way to generate cartesian product of arrays without using loops in bash?

One can use curly brackets to do a similar thing:

```
echo {a,b,c}+{1,2,3}
a+1 a+2 a+3 b+1 b+2 b+3 c+1 c+2 c+3
```

but I need to use arrays as inputs, and most obvious tricks fail me.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You could use brace expansion.  But it's ugly.  You need to use `eval`, since brace expansion happens before (array) variable expansion.  And `"${var[*]}"` with `IFS=,` to create the commas.

Consider a command to generate the string

```
echo {a,b,c}+{1,2,3}
```

Assuming the arrays are called `letters` and `numbers`, you could do that using the `"${var[*]}"` notation, with `IFS=,` to insert commas between the elements instead of spaces.

```
letters=(a b c)
numbers=(1 2 3)
IFS=,
echo {"${letters[*]}"}+{"${numbers[*]}"}
```

Which prints

```
{a,b,c}+{1,2,3}
```

Now add `eval`, so it runs that string as a command

```
eval echo {"${letters[*]}"}+{"${numbers[*]}"}
```

And you get

```
a+1 a+2 a+3 b+1 b+2 b+3 c+1 c+2 c+3
```

Comment: The only problem is with arrays containing just 1 element, as bash won't expand {a}+{1,2,3} properly.